# JavaScript automatic paste of pictures into html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site on which i have a navigation bar to the left, on which little images are shown. Per click onto them, the same as a big one will appear on the right.

I dont really know how to call it but i want to have a javascript, which scans a folder on my pc for jpg's and puts them into the html ínto the navigation div.

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me.

Have a nice day!

My HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scan.js" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="script.js" lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script> 

    <title> Galerie </title>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="caption"> <h1> Bildergalerie </h1> </div>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="navigation"> <!-- Navigationsleiste -->

            <img src="simson-kr51.jpg" alt="simson-kr51.jpg" title="simson-kr51.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-kr51.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-s51.jpg" alt="simson-s51.jpg" title="simson-s51.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-s51.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-s50.jpg" alt="simson-s50.jpg" title="simson-s50.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-s50.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-s53.jpg" alt="simson-s53.jpg" title="simson-s53.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-s53.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-sr1.jpg" alt="simson-sr1.jpg" title="simson-sr1.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-sr1.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-sr2.jpg" alt="simson-sr2.jpg" title="simson-sr2.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-sr2.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-duo.jpg" alt="simson-duo.jpg" title="simson-duo.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-duo.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-albatros.jpg" alt="simson-albatros.jpg" title="simson-albatros.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-albatros.jpg');" />
            <br />
            <img src="simson-sr50.jpg" alt="simson-sr50.jpg" title="simson-sr50.jpg" onclick="bildAnzeigen('simson-sr50.jpg');" />
            <br />

        </div>


        <div id="ansicht">  <!-- Großansicht -->

            <img id="grossesBild" src="simson-kr51.jpg" alt="simson-kr51.jpg" title="simson-kr51.jpg" />

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Script for getting a bigger picture:

```js
function bildAnzeigen(imgName) {  
var Bild = document.getElementById('grossesBild');   
Bild.src = imgName;  
Bild.alt = imgName;  
Bild.title = imgName;  
}
```

Comment: Show your code please.